# How to do suitable GetEnumerator() method for my own Stack<T> implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, iterator, stack

I have a problem with implementation GetEnumerator() method for my own generic Stack implementation. Below is fragment with code in my Stack class which extends generic IEnumerable, stack field is type: List. How can I create GetEnumerator() method so that the unit tests passed ? Or perhaps I made a mistake with creating Push and Pop methods ? Please help me and explain how and why my solution is not good enough.

```
    public void Push(T item)
    {
        this.stack.Add(item);
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        if (this.stack.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid operation pop, stack is empty.");
        }

        T value = this.stack[this.stack.Count - 1];
        this.stack.RemoveAt(this.stack.Count - 1);
        return value;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (this.stack == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Stack cannot be changed during iteration.");
        }

        for (int index = this.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            yield return this.stack[index];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

There are nunit tests, which are not passed with this code in my stack implementation.

```
    [Test]
    [Order(7)]
    public void Iterator_PopFromStack_Throw_InvalidOperationException()
    {
        Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(
            () =>
        {
            foreach (var item in this.stack)
            {
                this.stack.Pop();
            }
        }, "Stack cannot be changed during iteration.");
    }

    [Test]
    [Order(8)]
    public void Iterator_PushIntoStack_Throw_InvalidOperationException()
    {
        Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(
            () =>
        {
            foreach (var item in this.stack)
            {
                this.stack.Push(this.value);
            }
        }, "Stack cannot be changed during iteration.");
    }
```

Comment: So, how come you're reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

> Please help me and explain how and why my solution is not good enough.

It is not good enough cause it does not monitor for collection change during enumeration as the build in one [does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1.enumerator?view=net-6.0) (and as provided unit tests require):

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and the next call to `MoveNext` or `IEnumerator.Reset` throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

You can always look at the build into the framework [implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/Generic/Stack.cs,c5371bef044c6ab6) - it maintains [`_version`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/Generic/Stack.cs,bff230834b9ecdd2,references) field which is bumped on every manipulation (i.e. `Push` or `Pop`), is "cached" at the start of the enumeration and is checked on every [`MoveNext`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/Generic/Stack.cs,f504f9346dc9c3e9) invocation.

Since, it seems, that you are not using array as underlying storage you can use simpler implementation - the one [@Blindy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108796/blindy) suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one thing a stack isn't enumerable, since you can only ever access one element ever. So if you want it to be enumerable, what you're building isn't a stack, and you know that, because the backing collection you chose is `List<>`, not `Stack<>`.

With that out of the way, you seem to want the enumeration to throw an exception when the backing collection is changed. There are many ways of doing this, but the work is already done for you in the backing list, so you could simply do:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => stack.GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: _"for one thing a stack isn't enumerable"_ - .NET one [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Note, they'll need `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator()` as well

Comment: @GuruStron, yeah, I am aware, I've used `ElementAt()` on it before and my point stands: with a pure stack this shouldn't be possible, that's the whole reason to use a stack in the first place. `std::stack` doesn't allow this, for example.

Comment: @canton7, well that line should be the same as his own implementation, unless he did something crazy like copy and paste the generic enumerator code into the basic one :)